# Magento newsletter succeess message in pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I want to create fine pop up window for success message after submitting newsletter form . How I can do this with jquery js ? if I thinking right at first I need to check messages and if message = newsletter success message than show this mes in popup . right? but how can I realize this ? =) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have found three Method and I have applied it into my Magento:

**Method 1:**
Add to the top of the page you want to display the success message the following js script:

```
<script type=“text/javascript”>
var message = '<?php echo strip_tags($this->getChildHtml('global_messages')) ?>';
if (message == $this->__('Thank you for your subscription')) alert("What ever you want to display!");
```

**Method 2:**
A simple note saying, Thank you for your subscription.
Log into Magento Admin>CMS>Manage Pages>Add New Page
Create a Newsletter Policy CMS page, i.e. newsletter-promotions
Open SubscriberController.php file located in:

> MagentoStore\App\Code\Core\Mage\Newsletter\controllers\

Change

```
$session->addSuccess($this->__('Thank you for your subscription'));
```

to

```
$session->addSuccess($this->__('Thank you for your subscription. For more info on our Newsletter Policy, please click <a href="newsletter-promotions" target="_self">here</a>.'));
```

It would be a good idea to also do the same for; Please enter a valid email address; Confirmation request has been sent; and There was a problem with the subscription, messages.

**Method 3.**
Redirect to a special page of discounted products vieable only by subscribers, which contains the newsletter policy.

```
Magento Admin>Catalog>Manage Products>Add New Product
```

Create new special discounted products, with Visibilty attribute set to, Nowhere. Make a note of the product ID.

```
Magento Admin>CMS>Manage Pages>Add New Page
```

Create a Newsletter Policy CMS page, i.e. newsletter-policy-and-promotions. In this page you can add your special products you created for your new subscribers. (This is not covered in the scope of this, How To)
Change at approx line 65:

```
$this->_redirectReferer();
```

to

```
$this->_redirectUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl().'newsletter-policy-and-promotions');
$this->_redirectUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl());
```

to

```
$this->_redirectUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl().'newsletter-policy-and-promotions');
```

Now the subscriber will automatically be redirected to your new page, and the, “Thank you for your subscription” message will still be displayed.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: +1 - 5 mins from question to a great 3 option answer, you've had your coffee this morning!

Comment: thank u! I already found this post , and i tried to use 1st variant , but it didnt worked for me =(

Comment: try the second and third method

Comment: But I need to do this via js

Comment: Thank U =) I found another great solution http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/error.php/viewthread/22881/#t348405

Comment: you are welcome, accept the answer to hel other person with the same problem